# javascript enable scheduler

Tags: javascript, html, schedule

I all,
I have this code

```
<select id = 'jack'>
<option id = 'test1' >test1</option>
<option id = 'test2' >test2</option>
</select>

<input id="calendar" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

and this is the javascript

```
function enableEnd() {
end.attr('disabled', !this.value.length).datepicker('option', 'minDate', this.value);
}

var end = $('#calendar').datepicker();

$('#jack').datepicker({
onSelect: enableEnd
}).bind('input', enableEnd);
```

I would make sure that the schedule is active when I choose from the menu test1 while I would like to remain disabled if I choose test2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate the calendar when test1 is selected, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#jack').on('change', function (e) {
    if($('#jack').val()=="test1"){
      // enable the calendar
      $('#calendar').datepicker({
        format:"mm-dd-yyyy",
        autoclose: true
      });
    }else{
       $('#calendar').datepicker('remove');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: if user change from 'test1' to 'test2', the datepicker will be still enabled

Comment: I understood that he wants to activate the datepicker when test1 is selected. I updated my code so when selecting another value, the datepicker will be removed (disabled)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you are looking for this.

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").datepicker("option", "disabled", true);

$("#jack").on('change', function () {
    if($(this).val() == 'test1') {
        calendar.datepicker( "option", "disabled", false);
    } else {
        calendar.datepicker( "option", "disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way:

```
$('#jack').on('change', function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#calendar').attr('disabled', val == 'test2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's "change" is the way to go, I think. Then you've got a one-liner :

```
$('#jack').change(function() {
    $('#calendar').attr('disabled', $(this).val() == 'test2');
});
```

Fiddle here showing the desired behaviour : http://jsfiddle.net/y6pu4dwu/1/

Note : I'd suggest removing the "disabled" by default, since test1 will be selected at first.

Edit : this disables the HTML element itself, but the plugin exposes an API to disable (see other answers), so this is not the only way.